# How to retrieve a hasManyThrough in Laravel 5 controller

Tags: laravel-5

I have a setup where Spaces have posts, and posts may have links.  I need to filter out links that belong to private spaces.  Links table does not have a space_id column so it is my understanding that hasMany through could work for getting the links that belong to a space through the posts table.

I did google this, read the docs, and follow the suggested links here on SO but was unable to find anything that showed me the way.

I am getting an error as well with the lastest attempts

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$links
```

Space.php

```
public function posts() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

/** 
* A Space can have links through posts.
*
* The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access
* The second argument is the name of the intermediate model
*
* The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model
* The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model
*
*/

public function links() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Link', 'App\Post','space_id','post_id');
}
```

Post.php

```
public function links() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Link');
}

/** A Post belongs to a space.
*
*
*/
public function space() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Space');
}
```

Link.php

```
public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

What I am trying in the links controller is different variations of this

```
$private = Space::where('spaces.isPublic','=', 0)->get();
$privateLinks = $private->links();
```

but I have not been able to get it to work and am wondering if someone can show me the path there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$private->links()` returns a query builder, not a set of links.  You can use `$private->links` (no `()`) to get the collection of links themselves, or you can use `get()` on the query builder to retrieve them.  The query builder allows you to provide filters on the query, like `$private->links()->where('foo','bar')->get()`, but you have to call `get()` before you have the links.

`$private = Space::where('spaces.isPublic','=', 0)->get();` also returns a collection of Spaces.

You could do something like `$private[0]->links` or change it to `$private = Space::where('spaces.isPublic','=', 0)->first()` to get just the first private space, or you could go through all of the private spaces and do something with their links like:

```
foreach($private as $pr){ 
    $links = $pr->links;
    //dosomething
}
```

Comment: with that it gave me this error in the logs - Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$links, does this mean the models are off?